# Index was out of range.Error at "var file = Request.Files[0]"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateProject(ProjectInfoModel PI)
    {
        ProjectAttachmentModel fab = new ProjectAttachmentModel();
        bool abj = objPMSBAL.CreateProject(PI);


        // image upload for area master
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string Filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            //var filepath = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
            string ipath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Pictures"), Filename);

            file.SaveAs(ipath);
            fab = objPMSBAL.StoreImage(Filename, ipath);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("ProjectList1", abj);
    }// End
```

Comment: there are no files in Request.Files, check Request.Files should be null

Comment: Check for Request.Files.Count before var file = Request.Files[0]; statment

Comment: can you shown a bit of your markup? is your file control inside `form`? are you sumitting the form via ajax? is it a normal `POST`?

Comment: ya at control side and it is normal POST..

Comment: any tutorials about this to know..pls

Comment: here is a link http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Answer (score -1):

Add your code (not the controller) to your form: data-ajax="false".

The reason why you may be getting this error is because it is not possible to upload files using AJAX

Comment: the OP didnt specify the usage of AJAX?

Comment: yeah you're right. I had an error like this before and I jumped into conclusion